# python ProcessPoolExecutor

Tags: python, multiprocessing

У меня есть класс, парсер, который нужно запустить в многопроцессорности.
Я использую `ProcessPoolExecutor()` модуля `concurrent.futures` и в цикле передаю в класс парсера категорию и запускаю парсер.
Все работает в стольких процессах, сколько я указал в `max_workers` (допустим 4).
Но по истечению какого то времени, я замечаю, что работает всего 1 процесс. В диспетчере задач висят 4 процесса, но работает только 1.

Я не знаю, как отслеживать правильно, но приделал `enumerate` и этот номер так же передаю в парсер, который выводит принт номер категории из парсера по завершении парсинга.
И по началу все нормально, 1, 2, 3, 4 запустились одновременно и все идет ок.
3 категория допустим спарсилась быстрее 1,2,4.
Значит должен взять 5 категорию и парсить.
И так далее. Работая в 4 процесса каждая категория.
А у меня получается так, что стартуют одновременно, грубо говоря час работают одновременно, а потом остается 1 рабочий процесс, который парсит категории по очередно.

```py
with pool.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=4) as executor:
    for num, categories in enumerate(categories_all):
        parser = Parsers(categories=categories, count_category=num)
        executor.submit(parser.run)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В парсере, который вызывается метод `executor.submit(parser.run)` было написано еще многопоточность `ThreadPoolExecutor`. А в документации написано, что если в вызываемом `executor` объекте будет еще вызван `executor`, то это приведет к взаимоблокировке.
Исправил, проблем с этим теперь нет.